# Possible Reasons of Difference between DateTime.Now and DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net

I run the following c# code in my laptop,

```cs
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now-DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now-DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now-DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
```

which has difference results in different situations (actually I dont know which causes that difference).For example sometimes it becomes like that:

```
0
0
0
```

and sometimes like that:

```
-15,6084
0
0
```

The first reason I first think maybe hanging in first time JIT's code executing , then it become faster,for that reason there exists time lapse between calculations and that differ appears. Is that reasoning true ? or what is the main reason ?

Comment: Well, every single line, even every **statement** takes some time - and be it just a nanosecond. So if you evaluate `DateTime.Now` multiple times you surely get different results.

Comment: There's an *easy* way of verifying whether it's the JIT.  Run the method once, ignoring the result.  Then run the test.  The later tests won't be jitted, as that will have been done for the first, thrown-out, test.

Comment: Time keeps on slipping, slipping, into the fuuuture.  The clock is normally updated 64 times per second.  So 15.625 milliseconds, a bit more or less if the machine recently received a time server update.

Comment: My rule-of-thumb: If I need the value of DateTime.Now in a method several times (and it has to be the same value), I store the value into a local variable and use that instead of using the DateTime.Now property all the time.

Comment: Imagine it **never** gave a different answer (i.e. always 0). That would mean it is so fast that the two calls are always in the same 16 millisecond window. But let's take that to its logical conclusion. Call 1 and 2 must be in the same 16 millisecond window. Also for 2 and 3. And 3 and 4. And 1,001 and 1,002. And 1,000,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,000,000,001. Clearly, this is nonsense. The CPU can't execute unlimited operations in a given time slice (plus, time clearly doesn't stand still). Thus **by definition** it must not always return 0, regardless of the JIT.